# Wavelet decomposition for non-uniform 2D data sequences

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wavelet

I have a list which is almost surely some sort of a wave-like oscillation:

`y(x): {{x_1, y_1}, ...,{x_n, y_n}}`

and want to find wavelets that interpolate this data best using Mathematica. However, Mathematica's wavelet toolbox accepts standard sequential (uniform) series rather than non-uniform grids.

Possible solutions are either to firstly interpolate `y` to a uniform `x` grid and then proceed with wavelet decomposition or to find a fit to wavelet functions explicitly using FindFit routines without referring to the toolbox.

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Better suited to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does SE platform permit to move a question to its subsite? Is there a possibility to create a cross question?